# "Высшая ступень правосудия - исправление преступника"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

> Нельзя забывать и о том факте, что в Риме высшей ступенью правосудия
>   было исправление, а не наказание преступника.

На месте ли (своём) *ступень*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли - слишком разные понятия ставятся на "ступени", следующие одна за другой: директивная мера (осуждение) и её необязательный результат (исправление, но не в значении помещения в исправительное учреждение - это могло бы рассматриваться как следующая "ступень"). Понятие "ступень правосудия" изредка (и видимо, неформально) употребляется, но в значении *стадии судопроизводства* (например, стадия апелляции: 
https://rg.ru/2011/06/09/apellacia.html) или в составе метафоры "ступени дворца правосудия". Если попытаться заново сформулировать желаемое автором, то может получиться "**высшая степень проявления правосудия**".

Comment: Поправила на "цель" - вышла (ли) из положения?

Comment: А смертная казнь там была?

Comment: Ну ты ж и змий, однако... ***Нерон обвинил христиан в чудовищном пожаре Рима, и с 64 до 68 года христиан распинали на крестах, отдавали на съеденье зверям, обливали смолой и зажигали во время народных гуляний. Жертвами этих гонений в том числе стали и верховные апостолы – Пётр и Павел.***

Comment: Значит, "цель" можно только документально провозгласить и сослаться на соотв. грамоту. А в остальном "целью" правосудия где-либо и когда-либо является защита общества от преступности, а не исправление. Поэтому такое слово не убеждает.